# Accessing the variables from "robot publish" in a Jenkins declarative groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'd like to print some of the variables coming from robot's publish function, such as ROBOT_PASSRATIO, in the output of a Jenkins declarative script. This is of course written in Groovy.

However, when attempting to interpolate ${ROBOT_PASSRATIO} it comes out as null.

That values and others are also not in the environment variables, either. In non-declarative scripts, they've always been accessible just by calling them with ${}. So where are my variables? Do I need to do something specific to get robot to set them in env?

Answer (score 0):

Check that [Editable Email Notification](https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot/#user-content-using-token-macros-in-e-mail-report) is enabled in your project configuration.

Also make sure to interpolate `ROBOT_PASSRATIO` in a separate stage after Robot collects test results.

Comment: didn't see anyone respond to this. I have the robot test results in a separate stage from the emailext command. The variable not gets interpolated as "ROBOT_PASSRATIO is not supported in this context!"